# Allow horizontal scrolling of long math expressions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, mathjax, scrolling

Stack Exchange formats math, but often the formatted math is wider than the screen. It would be nice if formatted math were scrollable the same way that formatted code wider than the screen is scrollable.

Comment: Do you have an example? All my tests just word wrap the formulas.

Comment: On my device, the math here is wider than the screen unless I rotate my device https://mathoverflow.net/a/270357/83327

Comment: Oh the app, missed that tag. Also, nevermind my above comment, was able to repro with [certain cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDFsX.png) on desktop.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. If I start off too narrow, it wraps.  If I start of like you suggested, going from landscape to portrait, the math bock is wide but scrollable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6PKB.png

Comment: nm, I'm able to reproduce it.  Checking if it's a regression in the new MathJax version or something on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.6.1.

I recently updated MathJax and possibly due to a misconfiguration (or something) we're rendering MathJax as MathML rather than SVG.  That causes the CSS class to change from `MathJax_SVG_Display` to `MathJax_Display`, breaking my horizontal scrolling styles.

Comment: Thanks. Should I mark this as the answer?

Comment: @BallpointBen Sure.  Most people accept right away, some when the update goes out, and some never do.  It's your call.

Comment: Confirmed that this is fixed in v1.6.6