# A sliding/horizontal scrolling feature for reading responses

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I can't see whole responses on the mathematics site on mobile (iOS) because sometimes the LaTeX runs off of the screen. Can you add a horizontal scrolling feature please?

Comment: What version of the app do you have? This should have been [fixed in 1.6.6.1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296268/307988)

Comment: @Cai I have 1.6.5, 1.6.6.1 isn't listed as the current version on the App Store.

Comment: Oh right, well it'll be fixed once the update is pushed to the app store then

Comment: We have more than one mathematics site. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Mathematics. Not MathOverflow.